# using variables in a block from a parallel scope

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, objective-c-blocks, buildconfiguration

```
__block BOOL myBool = NO;
__strong MyClass *ptr = self;
self.footer.defaultSelectedItem.selectionBlock = ^{
    myBool = YES;
    ptr = nil;
};
```

This works just fine when my Scheme's *Build Configuration* is set to **Debug**, but I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I run with **Release**. The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happens on the the following line

```
if(selectionBlock != nil) selectionBlock();
```

but if I comment out all the lines inside my `selectionBlock` then it runs with no error. Why does this run in Debug and not Release?

FYI I'm using Automatic Reference Counting (arc)

** EDIT in response to @RobNapier **

The original code that works in debug is:

```
__block BOOL flag = NO;
__strong EventsView *ptr = self;
self.footer.defaultSelectedItem.selectionBlock = ^{
    if(flag) return;
    flag = YES;
    [ptr backTUI:nil];
    flag = NO;
};
```

Comment: Can we assume from the presence of `__strong` that you're using ARC?

Comment: Good point. Yes I'm using ARC.

Comment: What is "myObject = nil" here? Did you mean "ptr = nil"? From your other code, it looks like "myObject" is a class.

Comment: What does the `selectionBlock` @property look like?

Comment: The code as written doesn't make a lot of sense, so I'm wondering if you've abstracted the right part of the code. As written (on the assumption that you meant `ptr=nil` in the block), the entire myBool would likely be optimized away since nothing reads it. I assume there's actually more going on inside this block?

I'm guessing your use of `ptr` is to keep `self` from being deallocated until this block fires? This all feels very fragile. Since `self` isn't used in the block, it's not clear why that's important to you. You may need to expand the code a little.

Comment: @RobNapier per your points of obvious failure on my part, I added the actual code.

Comment: Is your `selectionBlock` property copying the block?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer good question: `@property(nonatomic, copy) SelectionBlock selectionBlock;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the life of me I could not get this to work with a block. So instead I moved to using a setter for the Event View pointer. I'm guessing that fixed the problem with my pointer by setting up an additional ARC retain. I'm still uncertain because I never saw a zombie get logged when using the block so yeah.

When in doubt, use a selector.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the extra `ptr` here. Using `self` inside the block would be more correct. The block will retain `self` in that case. That may cause a retain loop, so it's up to you to remember to set `self.selectionBlock = nil` at some point before `dealloc` to break the retain loop.

`flag` may be optimized away here. It's not clear how it could possibly be useful from the above code.

I'm always very nervous about long indirection-chains in a set operation like this one:

```
self.footer.defaultSelectedItem.selectionBlock = ...
```

I would make sure that `footer`, and the *current* `defaultSelectedItem` can't disappear before this runs.

Simplify the problem. Make the block just log "Running block." Then add back things until it crashes.

Comment: While all of this makes good sense, how is it that this works fine as is in debug mode, but not release mode? I see that I can optimize, but I don't see why this code is breaking just because of the mode change.

Comment: If your behavior relies on an undefined behavior (such as accessing something after it's been released), then it can easily work in debug but not release.

Comment: I'm finding that it is definitely the code inside the selection block that is causing the problem. I'm confused because the `self` I'm referring to is actually the `superView` of the object that is running my block. So it makes no sense that the code thinks the `self` is not there. How would something like that happen?

Comment: Well, it could happen if this block of code ran after the superview was removed from the screen. But have you confirmed that `self` is the problem rather than one of the other lines? Have you tried my `NSLog()` test to validate that something that does not access variables still has trouble?